# Handling IONIC 2 push notification

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created IONIC 2 App and have implemented the PUSH notification using ionic.io and it is working.

Next thing I need to implement is how App will respond on clicking at notification, like I am sending a payload variable "**postid**" with value '**1234**'.

Now there are two circumstances when App is open and when it is closed:

1) When App is open, I want to show a popup with push title and message with a go button - clicking on it will take to details page.

2) When notification received, clicking on it  will open the App and it will not show home page and will directly go to details page with a **postid** parameter.

My Code:

```
this.push.rx.notification()
  .subscribe((msg) => {           
    this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push(DetailsPage, {postid: 203146});
});
```

Issue with above code:

1) When App is closed -  it opens the App but do nothing but when I remove the parameter **postid** it navigates to **DetailsPage** but not with the parameter.

2) When App is open not sure how to do this as it do nothing when App is open.

Please suggest, Thanks!!

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: Yes, what are you looking for?

Comment: When app is closed push.rx.notification() is not called. When App is closed - it opens the App but do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code that resolved my issue.

Now it is working as desired. If there is a payload it will check for the payload and if not it will land at home page. If App is open then it will show a pop up box.

```
this.push.rx.notification()
              .subscribe((msg) => {
                let pushPayload = msg.payload;
                if(pushPayload == undefined)
                    return;

                if (msg.app.asleep || msg.app.closed) { 
                    if(pushPayload['postid'] !== undefined) {
                        this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push(DetailPage, {id: msg.payload['postid']});                        
                    }
                } else {
                    let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
                      title: msg.title,
                      message: msg.text,
                      buttons: [
                        {
                          text: 'Check Later',
                          handler: () => {
                            console.log('Disagree clicked');
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          text: 'Check Now',
                          handler: () => {
                            if(pushPayload['postid'] !== undefined) {
                                this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push(DetailPage, {id: msg.payload['postid']});        

                            } 
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    });
                    confirm.present();
                }
            });
```

Hope it may help someone.

Thanks

Comment: I'm using one signal for push notification and need to open specific page on notification clicked when app is open.Is anyway there?